# Como fazer com que os usuários entendam o propósito das tags?

Tags: debate, tags

Todos que acompanhem um pouco mais o site sabem que existe um certo comportamento entre os usuários de colocarem tags que **não se relacionem diretamente com a pergunta**.

Uma pergunta sobre uma exceção que é lançada em um programa C#, por vezes tem a tag [visual-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio). Em minha concepção, alguns acreditam que as tags servem para descrever aquilo que estão utilizando em seus projetos. [Uma pergunta para ilustrar o que disse.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/176058/1)

Ao marcar as tags em novas perguntas, o site mostra o seguinte na lateral da página para o AP:

> #### Como fazer uma tag
>
> Uma tag é uma palavra-chave ou etiqueta que classifica sua pergunta
>   junto com outras semelhantes. Escolha uma ou mais (até um máximo de 5)
>   tags que ajudarão aos respondedores a encontrarem e interpretarem sua
>   pergunta.
>
> ► complete a frase: minha pergunta é sobre...
>   **► use tags que descrevam coisas ou conceitos que são essenciais, não
>   incidentes a sua pergunta**
>   ► favor using existing popular tags
>   ► leia as descrições que aparecem abaixo da tag
>   Se a sua pergunta é principalmente sobre um tópico para o qual você
>   não consegue encontrar uma tag:
>   ► combine multiple words into single-words with hyphens (e.g.
>   asp.net-mvc), up to a maximum of 35 characters
>   ► creating new tags is a privilege; if you can't yet create a tag you
>   need, then post this question without it, then ask the community to
>   create it for you

Mesmo assim, esse comportamento reincide. O que podemos fazer (ou já fazemos) nesses casos, além da edição?

Comment: Se o usuário não conhece bem as tecnologias que está usando – e infelizmente isso é comum –, não tem como ele acertar as tags. Cabe à comunidade fazer isso.